# Upgrading zesty

Tags: upgrade, updates, python, kodi

PLEASE HELP!
I have zesty... i believe its Ubuntu budgie 17.04 with the kodi interface (17.3) and I need to change ASAP!
I'm still a newbie to Linux; last year someone put Budgie on for me (16.04 I believe) and I loved it but wanted a new flavour, so I'd  left it upgrading a month ago and was shocked to see that kodi had taken over my laptop! (as a media server I guess)
I can't get to my desktop, or apps/progs, so I can't  get online, nor access my writing or write! 
I must say though...All of my entertainment media is available and organized haha...PLEASE HELP ME 
I would LOVE to get rid of kodi, so I entered the command line "sudo apt-get remove kodi --auto-remove", to which it responds its not installed (wtf? How's that? It runs my pc! Kodi Krypton!) So I tell it to upgrade and it's unable to b/c zesty isn't supported anymore! I just ran: sudo apt-get upgrade and it says "unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt get update or --fix missing " no longer has release file

Comment: For the time being Ubuntu 16.04 has long time support till 2021. Zesty is not supported anymore. You just need to logout and pick up the `budgie desktop` in the display manager.

Comment: 17.04 is EOL (since 13-Jan-2018 when its 9 months of support ended), and to me putting Budgie on it would mean adding the Budgie desktop to your 17.04 machine (you can install multiple desktops on a machine which you select at login).  For 17.04 the mentions of `archive.ubuntu.com` in sources.list files need to be changed to `old-releases.ubuntu.com` (where post-EOL releases get placed).  My next comment will provide a link for more info.   Stick to LTS (long-term-support) releases if you want/need a longer life.

Comment: I haven't used Kodi in years (it was called 'xbmc' back then as i recall) but I used to exit/logout, then at the login screen select a normal DEsktop (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) and my normal gui would be run.  You MAY be able to do the same..

Comment: Thank you everyone! OK so now I got it to update then upgrade to artful...but kodi is still running the system it seems...posting pic in new question